# How can I set the maximum and minimum date of a datetimepicker through another datetimepicker

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I was just wondering if it is possible to edit the maximum date and minimum date of a datetime picker if the other datetimepicker's value changed because what I'm trying to do is that when I choose a date for my first datetimepicker it will automatically set the other datetimepicker to only selecting the next 7 days.

Comment: The best thing to do is to post your code so we see what you're trying to do.  Your English is ok, but "code is code" and can usually be read regardless of the programmer's native language.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTimePicker` control has a `ValueChanged` event (double-clicking the control will create the event handler method for you), which is triggered whenever the `Value` changes. In this event for the first `DateTimePicker`, you could set the `MinDate` and `MaxDate` properties of the second control:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker2.MinDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1);
    dateTimePicker2.MaxDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(7);
}
```

Once this is done, you can set a default date for the first control, and the second one will have it's min/max values set:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This will trigger the ValueChanged event when the form loads
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use MaxDate and MinDate.

> The control's MaxDate and MinDate properties determine the range of dates and times. The Value property contains the current date and time the control is set to. For details, see How to: Set and Return Dates with the Windows Forms DateTimePicker Control. The values can be displayed in four formats, which are set by the Format property: Long, Short, Time, or Custom. If a custom format is selected, you must set the CustomFormat property to an appropriate string. For details, see How to: Display a Date in a Custom Format with the Windows Forms DateTimePicker Control.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datetimepicker-control-overview-windows-forms

Comment: using codes brother, I know how to do it thru properties what I want to do is by using the first datetimepicker's textchanged

Comment: The link i pasted also has a link to the DateTimePicker Object which contains all the methods available for it which includes the onclick event method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker?view=netframework-4.7.2